# Code not fully parsing data

Tags: php, parsing, curl

I have the following code that looks at the wolfram alpha xml data and pull out the answer surrounded in the `<plaintext>` tags.  It works for the first tag, but not for after the answer.

Code:

```
<?php
$url = "http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input=what+day+is+today&appid=9QA6R9-VGL4AAURHU&format=plaintext&podtitle=Result";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
ob_start();
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $contents;
```

Here is the answer I get:

```
Monday, May 3, 2011</plaintext>
  </subpod>
 </pod>
 <sources count='2'>
  <source url='http://www.wolframalpha.com/sources/AstronomicalDataSourceInformationNotes.html'
      text='Astronomical data' />
  <source url='http://www.wolframalpha.com/sources/PeopleDataSourceInformationNotes.html'
      text='People data' />
 </sources>
</queryresult>
```

Comment: Hello! It works fine for me. Remember to view-source and not just what the browser displays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$url = "http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input=what+day+is+today&appid=9QA6R9-VGL4AAURHU&format=plaintext&podtitle=Result";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
ob_start();
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

function get($a,$b,$c){
     $y = explode($b,$a);
     $x = explode($c,$y[1]);
    return $x[0];
}

echo get($contents,'<plaintext>','</plaintext>');
?>
```

Comment: Which line do I put that in?  I don't understand where it's supposed to go.

Comment: replace it with `echo $contents;`, also that's just for your viewing pleasure, you can already work with this information fine. The only reason it showed weirdly was because you were viewing it in the browser.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I changed to code to get only contents within plaintext.